How to evaluate Integral : $\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\text{arccot}(x)}{1-x}dx$
How to evaluate Integral :
$$\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\text{arccot}(x)}{1-x}dx$$
\begin{align*}
I&=\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\text{arccot}(x)}{1-x}dx \overset{t=1/x}{=}\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\arctan(t)}{t(t-1)}dt \\ &= \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\arctan(x)}{1-x}dx-\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x}dx
\end{align*}
It seems very complicated with these integrations.
I need help in evaluating the integration. Thank you very much.

you have problems near $1$

WolframAlpha says it doesn't converge.  Are you sure you typed the bounds correctly?

WolframAlpha cannot perform improper integrals.  See below.

$$-I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan t}{t(1-t)}dt=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^N \frac{\arctan t}{t(1-t)}dt=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\int_0^N \frac{\arctan t}tdt+\int_0^N \frac{\arctan t}{1-t}dt\right)$$
$$=\lim_{N\to\infty}\big(I_1(N)+I_2(N)\big)$$
$$I_1(N)=\int_0^N \frac{\arctan t}tdt\overset{IBP}{=}\ln t\,\arctan t\,\bigg|_0^N-\int_0^N \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt$$
$$=\ln N\arctan N-\int_0^N \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt\tag{1}$$
The second integral can be evaluated in the principal value sense
$$I_2(N)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left(\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{\arctan t}{1-t}dt+\int_{1+\epsilon}^N \frac{\arctan t}{1-t}dt\right)$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left(-\ln(1-t)\arctan t\,\bigg|_0^{1-\epsilon}-\ln(t-1)\arctan t\,\bigg|_{1+\epsilon}^N+\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2}dt+\int_{1+\epsilon}^N \frac{\ln(t-1)}{1+t^2}dt\right)$$
$$=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\big(\ln\epsilon\arctan(1+\epsilon)-\ln\epsilon\arctan(1-\epsilon)-\ln(N-1)\arctan N\big)$$
$$+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2}dt+\int_0^{N-1}\frac{\ln t}{1+(1+t)^2}dt\tag{2}$$
$$-I(N)=I_1(N)+I_2(N)=\ln N\arctan N-\ln(N-1)\arctan N$$
$$-\int_0^N \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2}dt+\int_0^{N-1}\frac{\ln t}{1+(1+t)^2}dt$$
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}-I(N)=-\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2}dt+\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln t}{1+(1+t)^2}dt$$
Making the substitution $t\to\frac1t$ we notice, that the first integral is zero
$$I=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2}dt-\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln t}{1+(1+t)^2}dt\tag{3}$$
where
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2}dt\overset{t\to\frac1t}{=}\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(t-1)}{1+t^2}dt-\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln t}{1+(t+1)^2}dt-G=\frac{\pi\ln2}8-G$$
$$\boxed{\,\,I=G-\frac{\pi\ln2}4\,=0.37156907...\,\,}$$

Notice $$
\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\text{arccot}(x)}{1-x}dx \overset{t=1/x}{=}\int^{\infty}_{1} \frac{\arctan(t)}{t(t-1)}dt 
$$
So you can map the integration interval $[0, 1]$ to $[1, \infty)$ and write the result as an improper integral (Cauchy principal value) over $[1, \infty)$:
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\text{arccot}(x)}{1-x}dx = \int^{\infty}_{1} \frac{\text{arctan(x) -x arccot}(x)}{x(x-1)} dx = \int^{1}_{0} \frac{\text{arctan(x) -x arccot}(x)}{x(x-1)} dx 
$$
where the last expression is derived by again substituting $x = 1/t$.
The transformed integrand has finite values ($ π/2 - 1$) at $x\to 0^+$ and ($1 - π/4$) at $x=1$, it does not have singularities in $(0, \infty)$.
The integral can be performed by noting that in $(0, 1]$ we have $\text{arccot}(x) = \pi/2 - \text{arctan(x)}$, so we need to evaluate
$$
\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\text{arctan(x) -x arccot}(x)}{x(x-1)} dx = \int^{1}_{0} \frac{(x+1)\text{arctan}(x) -x \pi / 2 }{x(x-1)} dx  \\
= \int^{1}_{0} \frac{\text{arctan}(x) }{x} dx  + \int^{1}_{0} \frac{-x \pi / 2 + 2 \text{arctan}(x) }{x(x-1)} dx
$$
The first integral gives Catalan's number $C \simeq 0.915966$. The integrand of the second integral is finite at both $x=0$ and $x = 1$ and the integral can be evaluated, giving   $- \frac{\pi\ln2}4 \simeq -0.544397$. So the result is
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\text{arccot}(x)}{1-x}dx = C - \frac{\pi\ln2}4 
\simeq 0.371569
$$

You haven't addressed the concern near $x=1$; the original integral doesn't converge.

I addded the integrand's value at x=1.

$\text{arccot}(1)=\pi/4;$ $1-1=0$; $(\pi/4)/0 = ???$

@Integrand You got me wrong: the integration is performed as an improper integral, the value at x=1 is the value after transformation, showing that (only then) the divergence is resolved.

I added some more explanation in the text.

$\int_0^1 \frac{\text{arccot} x}{x-1}dx$ is already an improper integral, which diverges

Show me the error in the computation and we can talk.  The "improperness" here comes from adding a positive "infinite" value $\int^{1}{0} \frac{\text{arccot}(x)}{1-x}dx $ and a negative "infinite" value$\int^{\infty}{1} \frac{\text{arccot}(x)}{1-x}dx $, and exploiting that these infinite values indeed cancel out, the result being finite. Under strict definitions of a Riemann integral, we agree that you cannot do this.

are you talking about the principal value?

Yes, principal value explains it.

A lot more work is necessary to handle the principal value here.

By splitting the integral at $x=1$ and $x\to\tfrac1x$ trick
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{x\operatorname{arccot} x-\arctan x}{x(1-x)}dx.$$
By means of the Maclaurin series $\operatorname{arccot}x=\tfrac\pi 2-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$, $\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$ and using the identity $\frac\pi 4=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ we have
$$I=\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x}\right)dx$$
and
$$I=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}(H_{2n+1}+H_{2n}).$$
Using the identities
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}H_{2n}=1-\frac{\pi} {8}\ln2,$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}H_{2n+1}=G-\frac{\pi} {8}\ln2$$
we have $I=G-\frac{\pi\ln2}4$ where $G$ is the Catalan"s constant and $H_n$s are harmonic numbers.
